# Memory allocation for chart images

Tags: asp.net, mschart

I am trying to have `chart images` with key as

```
<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=memory;deleteAfterServicing=false;  privateImages=false;" />
```

in web.config. When does this memory gets cleared and wheather the client or the server memory is being used for this? Thanks in advance